# Custom element bindable not working

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So I have the follow custom element:

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {customElement, bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('wave-canvas')
@inject(Element, Router)
@bindable({name:'hasGenerate', defaultValue:true})
export class WaveCanvas {
    constructor(element, router) {
        this.router = router;
        this.element = element;

    }

    goHome() {
        this.router.navigate('welcome');
    }

    attached() {
        let initialEvent = new CustomEvent('init', {
            bubbles: true
        });
        this.element.dispatchEvent(initialEvent);

    }
}

<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h3>${router.currentInstruction.config.title}</h3>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-right" style="padding-top: 10px">
            <button class="btn" click.trigger="goHome()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <canvas id="theCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 5px"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form submit.trigger="submit()" class="">
                <content select="form-elements"></content>

                <button show.bind="hasGenerate" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Generate</button>
            </form>
            <content select="other-values"></content>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Being used as such:

```
<template>
    <div class="container z-depth-2">
        <require from="../components/wave-canvas"></require>
        <wave-canvas hasGenerate="false" init.delegate="setInitialContent($event)">
            <form-elements>
            </form-elements>
            <other-values>
            </other-values>
        </wave-canvas>
    </div>

</template>
```

For this instance of wave-canvas I would like to hide the Generate button, but the way I have it currently setup, it does not work. If I change the default value in the view model, it does hide as expected, but not when I specify the attribute in the html as false. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aurelia will hyphenate mixed case bindable property names, custom element names and custom attribute names.  This is necessary because the DOM lower-cases all element and attribute names.

Try `has-generate`:

```js
<wave-canvas has-generate="false" ...
```

You might also want to use `has-generate.bind="false"`. This way `false` (boolean) will be assigned to your element's `hasGenerate` property (as opposed to the string `'false'`).